# javascript - object of inherited class can access all the parent's properties and methods

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

My code like this:

```
function Person(firstName) {
     "use strict";
     this.firstName = firstName;
     this.fullName = "ABC";
     this.greeting = function (name) {
         console.log("Hi " + name);
     };
}

Person.prototype.hello = function () {
    "use strict";
    console.log("Hello");
};

function Car(model, year) {
    "use strict";
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;
}

Car.prototype = new Person();
var mercedes = new Car("CS300", 2017);
mercedes.greeting("mer");
console.log(mercedes.fullName );
```

Why can the object *Mercedes* access the property *fullName* and the method *greeting()* even if I declare them directly in the constructor *Person* out of *Person.prototype* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ia happening because the prototype of the `Car` it uses the `Person` function. So, when a key is not found on the `mercedes` the JavaScript engine what look up to the prototype chain to find it.

You could access the prototype object as `mercedes.__proto__`, in order to verifiy this. Check the following snippet.

```js
function Person(firstName) {
"use strict";
this.firstName = firstName;
this.fullName = "ABC";
this.greeting = function (name) {
    console.log("Hi " + name);
    };
}

Person.prototype.hello = function () {
    "use strict";
    console.log("Hello");
};

function Car(model, year) {
    "use strict";
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;
}

Car.prototype = new Person();
var mercedes = new Car("CS300", 2017);

console.log(mercedes.__proto__);
```

Generally, speaking if the JavaScript engine doesn't find the key you are looking for at the proto of your object, then it goes up to the proto of the proto, in order to find there the key. This is happening until either we found the key or reach the null (the end of any prototype chain). If we reach `null` then we would get the message that the key we are looking for is `undefined`, since it wasn't found anywhere in the prototype chain. For instance, let's look to find the value of key `foo` for mercedes.

```js
function Person(firstName) {
"use strict";
this.firstName = firstName;
this.fullName = "ABC";
this.greeting = function (name) {
    console.log("Hi " + name);
    };
}

Person.prototype.hello = function () {
    "use strict";
    console.log("Hello");
};

function Car(model, year) {
    "use strict";
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;
}

Car.prototype = new Person();
var mercedes = new Car("CS300", 2017);

console.log(mercedes.foo);
```

As you notice now `undefined` is printed on console.

This is called [prototypal inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) and it is the mechanism through which inheritance is implemented in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Prototypal inheritance. mercedes = Car = Person. If you call a method, javascript searches the current object for that method and if it doesn't find it, it goes up the tree until it does or doesn't. In  your case it finds it on Person.

Comment: thank you, i understand now how the inheritance works